# Word add-in: Get whole document but File.getSliceAsync method not returning

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I'm creating an Office Add-in and am having trouble with the javascript file.getFileAsync method in Word Online (Word 2013 desktop is fine).

I'm using sample code from github...

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-powerpoint-or-word.md

My code looks like this...

```
function getFile() {
        Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Text,
            { sliceSize: 65536},
            function (result) {

                if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {

                    // Get the File object from the result.
                    var myFile = result.value;
                    var state = {
                        file: myFile,
                        counter: 0,
                        sliceCount: myFile.sliceCount
                    };

                    getSlice(state);
                }
            });
    } 

    function getSlice(state) {
        state.file.getSliceAsync(state.counter, function (result) {
            if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                sendSlice(result.value, state);
                state.file.closeAsync();
            }
            else if(result.status == 'failed')
                state.file.closeAsync();
        });
    }
```

Before calling file.getSliceAsync the data looks good - myFile.sliceCount is 1. The result function is never called and no errors are thrown in the console.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: this issue is fixed and live. Please try it again it must work now.
thanks!

---------------- **ORIGINAL ANSWER JUST FOR REFERENCE** ----------------------------

Yes, there is a regression right now in Word Online preventing the code to run successfully. The specific issue is that the file.getSliceAsync method is never calling the call-back function. This only happens with the TEXT type, if you want to get the docx or pdf this should work ok. This issue will be fixed in a couple of weeks.

You have an alternative if you want to get the text of the document you can use the new APIs for Word check out this sample:

```js
Word.run(function(context) {
      var myBody = context.document.body;
      context.load(myBody);
        
        return context.sync()
        .then(function(){
            console.log(myBody.text);
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps!
Thanks for reporting this issue!
Juan.

Comment: Thanks Juan. Regarding your snippet, I assume because it's the new API that it won't work on Word 2013?

Comment: And this regression makes me wonder if many people are using this older Dialog 1.1 API - maybe most people have migrated to the new Word API?

Comment: Yeah, it's fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JuanBalmori. I have an issue with that function too. I'm trying to get a Pdf document, however all the pages are blank. Do you know something about this?

Comment: @Niko can you please  provide more details on the platforms and versions you are experiencing this?

Comment: @JuanBalmori, Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516394/getting-whole-document-returns-empty-pdf

When saving in django server it works. There is something with saving in JS

Comment: @JuanBalmori, Could you please have a look at this also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410474/word-web-addin-getsliceasync-only-return-first-slice-of-data).

Comment: @Asmi ok lets chat there :)

Comment: Sure! My similar addin seems to be working fine for powerpoint , excel but not in word. Please Suggest!

Comment: the issue was removed :(